# HelloAndroid]emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch'!

Tags: android

I am new to Android. Follow the HelloAndroid Tutorials by use Eclipse. 
After run HelloAndroid, the AVD 'xian_avd2' lunched, but stop there, no " Hello, Android"
displayed on AVD. Looks like Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

Not know how to resolve this, please help.
Thanks
wang813

```
[2010-01-29 00:12:13 - HelloAndroid]------------------------------
[2010-01-29 00:12:13 - HelloAndroid]Android Launch!
[2010-01-29 00:12:13 - HelloAndroid]adb is running normally.
[2010-01-29 00:12:13 - HelloAndroid]Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2010-01-29 00:12:13 - HelloAndroid]Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'xian_avd2' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2010-01-29 00:12:14 - HelloAndroid]Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'xian_avd2'
[2010-01-29 00:12:37 - HelloAndroid]New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2010-01-29 00:12:37 - HelloAndroid]Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2010-01-29 00:13:59 - HelloAndroid]emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch'!
```

Answer (score 10):

1. Open Android Virtual Device Manager
2. select the AVD you use for your app.
3. Press the start button and wait for a new form to show up called (Launch Options).
4. Check the box "Wipe user data" and hit "Launch" button.

This should work.

--- OR ---

1. Open Android Virtual Device Manager
2. Delete the AVD you use for your app.
3. Create an new AVD.
4. Start your new AVD.

This should also work.

Answer (score 7):

Try to use the command `emulator -avd emulator_name -wipe-data`

Answer (score 7):

The problem as I discovered lays in the fact the the project has no appropriate Virtual Device defined for it in the AVD manager.

*So the recommended steps in eclipse are:*

1. Go to "Project"-> Properties-> Android.
2. On the right pane see what line is checked in the Project build target. 
   *Remember the target platform number* that appears in the selected line.
3. Go to "Windows"-> AVD Manager.
4. Check the list of existing Android Virtual Devices for a device that matches the Platform and API level that you have set for your project (see step #2 above).
5. If there is no line that includes an AVD for your platform (as I suspect), add it using the "New" button.
6. A "Create New Android Virtual Device" window will be opened. set a new device name. in the "Target" selection box choose the right platform for your project.

Enjoy your emulator once again!

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar problem -- it ended up I wasn't waiting long enough for the emulator to run the OS before trying to install the app. Launch the emulator and then wait for the home screen to appear before running the app in Eclipse.

Comment: I tried waiting in this case and got the following error: "ERROR: the user data image is used by another emulator. aborting"

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it's an AVD problem for existing machine. Try to create a new AVD from the AVD Manager and delete the old one.

Answer (score 2):

This can happen on slow computers when the emulator doesn't start in time. When it eventually does start, it is no longer connected to ADB. The solution is to restart ADB so that it reconnects to the emulator. You can do this by executing the following in command line:

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, I believe it happened due to an unexpected power failure while the emulator was running. Having it not shut down properly meant that my session was still cached. (I would occasionally get these errors too):

```
[2012-06-08 05:05:06 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
[2012-06-08 05:05:06 - Emulator] WARNING: SD Card image already in use: C:\Users\Ben\.android\avd\Ben-Android.avd/sdcard.img
[2012-06-08 05:05:06 - Emulator] WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
```

If this happened to you, pull up the command line, navigate to your android-sdk\tools and follow the corrected top post: emulator -avd emulator_name -wipe-data

Answer (score 2):

I resolved it (Mac) by following these steps,

- Run Emulator
- Keep the Emulator, (no matter same error occurs)
- Make Sure the Home Screen of Emulator is appeared
- go to Window -> Show Perspective -> DDMS --> In Devices Panel -> on Corner Drop Down Menu -> Reset adb

I Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

for me didn't worked:

```
./emulator -noaudio @androidDev1
```

so I used:

```
./emulator @androidDev1
```

and it worked perfectly! :)

Also check Eclipse IDE:

```
Windows->Preferences->Android->Launch->Options
```

It should be empty

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, I deleted my AVD and created afresh - after that I do not see such problems.

Answer (score 1):

also same problem for me..

go to DDMS perspective-->select Device-->go to Window-->Navigation-->Show view menu-->reset adb..
it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Disable snapshot and don't use it. It is what solved this issue in my case

Answer (score 0):

delete the avd and create another helped me

Answer (score 0):

Try 1 more time. If it occurs again

Goto Project->clean and

Right click your project and choose refresh..

Answer (score 0):

This worked on Linux for me:

- Run Emulator (Wait for the home screen of the Emulator to load)
- Click Window > Open Perspective > DDMS
- In Devices Panel, click on drop down menu > Reset adb
- Run project

Answer (score 0):

It comes down to just making a new AVD with moderate settings, at least that's what fixed it for me. Though every time I close it I have to make a new one. Guess just wait for a patch.

Click Android Device Manager button on the second toolbar.

Click New.

Set up a mid-range device, basically just select a phone model from the middle of the list that isn't a tablet. The memory should fill it self in, then just put like 20mb for the SD card.

Click Start. The AVD will now start up and load the Android OS.

Then Run your app on said device.

Once you get this problem it seems to remain unless you do a full reinstall... Basically, always start the AVD first, let it hit the android home screen, then run your app. This way Eclipse doesn't overload the sluggish emulator.

Answer (score 0):

And I got the solution from [here](http://www.atriagrawal.com/2011/11/android-error-2011-11-12-001359-helloandroidemulator-5554-disconnected-cancelling-com-example-helloandroid-helloandroid-activity-launch/). It perfectly works for me.