# Why do I get a emulator-5554 disconnected message

Tags: android, emulation

When I start my android emulator it takes some times then it will show the emulator-5554 disconnected message. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HelloAndroid\]emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch'!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160454/helloandroidemulator-5554-disconnected-cancelling-com-example-helloandroid-he)

Answer (score 30):

Open the Device view of Android in Eclipse IDE. Then click the Reset Adb menu item on the device menu. Then run your application again.[image]

Comment: The list of devices is empty for me; when I click *Reset Adb*, the device running in the emulator appears for a while, then it disappears again and another *disconnected* message appears in the console output.

Answer (score 12):

I resolved it by following these steps,

- Run Emulator
- Keep the Emulator, (no matter same error occurs)
- Make Sure the Home Screen of Emulator is appeared
- go to Window -> Show Perspective -> DDMS --> In Devices Panel -> on Corner Drop Down Menu
- Reset adb

I Hope it will helps you.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Restart the emulator

```
Select & Right Click on Android Project
Run Configurations
Go to tab Target 
Enable option Wipe User Data on Emulator launch parameters
Run Application
```

If you are using other IDE, you can restart your emulator using -wipe-data flag to delete all the temporary files that the emulator created in previous runs.

Answer (score 5):

Note that to find the "reset adb" option you have to click the downward pointing arrow next to the camera on the right of the devices view. The arrow may appear greyed out like everything else on the devices toolbar. It used to take hours sometimes for a successful emulator launch because of the constant disconnects until i discovered this option and where it was buried.

Answer (score 3):

I've faced the same situation today: started emulator from AVD manager, and after start it appeared offline in DDMS, resetting ADB didn't help - it attempted to start several times and resulted the same way, with offline status. Another symptom was that emulator didn't react on clicking on it. After all I realized that the reason was that emulator has saved the last execution state, which possibly crashed. To fix it I unchecked the 'Launch from snapshot' option on start of emulator. And this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

[See Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160454/helloandroidemulator-5554-disconnected-cancelling-com-example-helloandroid-he/18628327#18628327)

[Another related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994026/failed-to-install-helloandroid-apk-on-device-emulator-5554/18628540#18628540)

[And another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763395/issue-with-hello-android-tutorial/18628585#18628585)

This worked on Linux for me:

- Run Emulator (Wait for the home screen of the Emulator to load)
- Click Window > Open Perspective > DDMS
- In Devices Panel, click on drop down menu > Reset adb
- Run project

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me, apparently another application (VideoStream in my case) was using the same port as the adb. To fix this, use the PowerShell (with elevated permissions) to look for the process that is using the port in which you get the error:

```
Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort portNumber).OwningProcess
```

You will know the PID because it shows on the Id column.

Then open Task Manager and right click on the item bar on top (Name, Status...) and enable PID to view the process id. Then look for the PID that you got on the search before and kill it.

This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

That seems to be a problem of 1.6

Upgrade to 2.1 and it shall disappear.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Goto-->Prefrencess-->Android-->DDMS--> 1.visible the checkbox Use ADBHost,
2.ADB Connection timeout to 1000000,
3.Method Profile Buffer size change from 8MB into 20MB.

This is Solution the Developer whom have the lower end machine will face this Problem.
Kindly check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the emulator from the AVD Manager. Wait till you get the home screen and then run your project.

Answer (score -3):

The problem as I discovered lays in the fact the the project has no appropriate Virtual Device defined for it in the AVD manager.

*So the recommended steps in eclipse are:*

1. Go to "Project"-> Properties-> Android.
2. On the right pane see what line is checked in the Project build target. 
   *Remember the target platform number* that appears in the selected line.
3. Go to "Windows"-> AVD Manager.
4. Check the list of existing Android Virtual Devices for a device that matches the Platform and API level that you have set for your project (see step #2 above).
5. If there is no line that includes an AVD for your platform (as I suspect), add it using the "New" button.
6. A "Create New Android Virtual Device" window will be opened. set a new device name. in the "Target" selection box choose the right platform for your project.

Enjoy your emulator once again!