# Eclipse Doesn't Recognize my Android Device

Tags: eclipse, debugging, android

I have the samsung galaxy tab, when I plug it into to eclipse to run and debug my apps. Eclipse doesn't recognize the device. When I try it with my friend's Droid 2 it still doesn't work. Can someone please help me?

Comment: What environment are you developing under? OS X, Linux or Windows?

Comment: If you are developing under Windows you will have to get the drivers for each device and install them locally.

Comment: 1)Install usb drivers
2)Enable usb debugging on your device
I did all of the above but didnt work.
then i did the things in the following link http://stackoverflow.com/a/8705561/538408 and adb recognized my device

Answer (score 21):

If you are developing with Windows, you might need to install the USB driver for our device. For Windows 7, here's how you do it:

To install the Android USB driver on Windows 7 for your device:

1. Connect your Android-powered device to your computer's USB port.
2. Right-click on Computer from your desktop or Windows Explorer, and select **Manage**.
3. Select **Devices** in the left pane.
4. Locate and expand **Other device** in the right pane.
5. Right-click the device name (such as Nexus S) and select **Update Driver Software**. This will launch the Hardware Update Wizard.
6. Select **Browse** my computer for driver software and click **Next**.
7. Click **Browse** and locate the USB driver folder. (The Google USB Driver is located in \extras\google\usb_driver.)
8. Click **Next** to install the driver.

Check [**this link**](http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html) for more information if you need it.

Comment: I've tried this, but it's not working; the device in question is an extremely cheap tablet (a Time2 7" slate running ICS) not listed in the OEM driver list.  It's about the third Android device I have.  Looking at the link you included it seems it solves the problem if it's your *first* Android device, but not necessarily for subsequent devices.  I think it is the driver, though, because the device is showing a yellow warning triangle in the management console.  Any ideas?

Comment: I had the same problem, an off brand "AVATAR" 7" tablet that wouldn't recognize. I found some other link: http://www.moborobo.com/ and that thing installs some "generic" driver that made it work.

Answer (score 19):

Have you tried:

Settings -> Applications -> Development - Enable USB Debugging

Answer (score 16):

In android 4.2.* The “Developer Options” menu item is gone!

Answer: The “Developer Options” menu item on 4.2.* is hidden.

1. Goto Settings -> About Phone.
2. Goto “Build Number” at the end of the Scroll list.
3. Tap on “Build Number” repeatedly (7 times).  On your third tap you should see message indicating that you only have 4 more taps to go to ‘become a developer’.
4. Continue: 4 more taps.
5. Hooray, you are now a ‘Developer’, go back to the Setting page.
6. You should see Developer Option menu item in your setting list now.
7. Open Developer Options and check USB debugging > Ok

****it's work for me****

Reference : http://www.wugfresh.com/faq/how-do-i-enable-usb-debugging-on-android-4-2-the-developer-options-menu-item-is-gone/

Comment: worked, but for me: settings - about - software information - more - build number

Answer (score 4):

download the samsung software Kies .it detects samsung deivces

Go to http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html and follow up

this solution worked for me

Comment: This works ... SOMETIMES. Then it stops working, for days at a time. It appears to be a bug in Samsung's customized OS, that they are/were *very* slow to fix. A brand new retail S3 (bought March 2013) has this bug out-of-the-box :(.

Comment: This just worked for me. Kies installed the drivers and Eclipse now lets me choose my device from Running Devices. I can now test my App on my tablet. +1

Answer (score 4):

In addition to **Settings -> Applications -> Development - Enable USB Debugging**, click on the following option:

**Revoke USB debugging authorization**

And then plug the device again.

Answer (score 4):

Addition to Tor-Morten's answer: Only checking the Developer setting for USB debugging may not be enough. The USB connection setting (Android 4.4: Settings -> Storage -> Option Menu -> USB computer connection) needs to be checked for either "Media device" or "Camera" before it will be shown in Eclipse's Android Device Chooser window.

Comment: That's the key man! It's new in 4.4.X. I was freaking out, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe its a matter of how you plugged the device onto your computer. I'm using a mac and pluged the usb into one of the keyboard slots. It doesn't find anything even you've installed Kies with all its new drivers. 
After plugging it directly into one of the slots at the computer the device has been recognized imediately.

Even it is a beginner mistake....maybe it helps :)

Comment: The same thing happens with the right-hand slot on iMacs (never works, ever, for Samsung devices) - my guess is this is a bug with the Apple hardware / OS X.

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly common problem.  You basically don't have the drivers you need for USB debugging.

There are a few different ways I've had to obtain drivers for phones.  The first way you should attempt is to go into the Android SDK and AVD manager and download the Google USB driver debug package.

This may or may not give you the driver you need.  If it doesn't you will have to do one of two things.  One, add the device details to the driver file you just downloaded.  Generally these will be posted on forums/boards discussing your phone type.  Secondly, you can download a different driver from another source like the phone manufacturer.

Comment: The Samsung drivers are available at http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do#01

Comment: Updated link: http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=9480 . Works like a charm for my Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 with Monodroid so it should work with Eclipse as well.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your account has admin privileges. I installed my Motorola drivers without elevating, and although the install ran smoothly it never associated them to the device. Once I ran as admin, worked like a charm.

Comment: That would be a solution if *nothing* recognised the device.  If only Eclipse fails to detect it, it may not be the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Linux you can try on terminal the following steps. Don't forget to have your device plugged in. Use sudo if doest work.

- adb kill-server
- adb start-server
- adb devices (see if device is recognized)

Answer (score 1):

Ι had the same problem:

While i had activated the debugging options on my phone (Samsung Galaxy S Duos Black), eclipse couldn't find the device because the usb drivers failed to download or something and so in the Device Manager (win7) i saw only Android and CSC something, all yellow and with no installed drivers.
 

 I tried to download the Samsung drivers manually, but this failed to work.

What REALLY worked was downloading+installing Samsung Kies, connecting my device through usb and at first it failed again to put the drivers, then i disconnected the device, pressed some troubleshooting errors button that was on the main screen (NOT the lite version, the normal one), that took some time, re-connected the device and voila, the drivers were installed successfully and both the Device Manager and eclipse recognised the device.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my LG G3 phone. 
I tried to re-install the driver as explained here: http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html
 Nothing helped. Fortunately on the very same page I have found the link to LG firmware site: http://www.lg.com/us/support/software-firmware

So I did the following:

- Connect the phone to the PC using the USB cable
- Uninstalled the Google's USB driver (My Computer->Management->Devices->Portable Devices->MyPhone: uninstall)
- Download driver for my LG G3 phone (LG885) from the LG site
- Install this driver
- Got on the phone screen request to approve the new RCA key and allow debugging.
- Try to Run an Android project in Eclipse.
- PROBLEM SOLVED.

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem.
I saw that the product was correctly defined under Device Manager, but Eclispe did not show the product in the target.

The easy way was to install Samsung Kies and to see that the following command:
...eclipse\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\platform-toolsadb\adb device 
gives me some output instead of only "List of devices attached".
once it recognizes the product, use "run configuration" choosing target "Active devices" under    "Launch on all compatible devices/AVD's" radio button.

still, you don't get the product on the list as expected but it works.
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on windows with my samsung galaxy device .. installing [samsung kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had loads of problem getting this to work when I switched to a new computer.
I downloaded and installed Kies, but Windows 7 still didn't recognize my device.
My problem was the proxy my company use, Kies tries to download USB drivers in the installation, but fails silently and finishes the installation.

You might have this problem if your USB Driver folder in the installation is empty (i.e C:\Program Files (x86)\Samsung\Kies\USB Driver).

Solution for me: install Kies without a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Unload EasyTether extension.
This worked for me - look at the part about unloading the EasyTether extension. adb not finding my device / phone (MacOS X) I was able to connect my samsung galaxy note 2 to macbook pro snow leopard.

Answer (score 0):

Download new USB driver for samsung/pc connection here:
http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-Andorid-USB-Driver-for-Windows

After enabling developer mode and USB debugging of course.
The phone should ask to accept the pc location as secure after USB driver upgrade.
Installing KIES did not fix the problem on my Galaxy Note 3.