# test android application in mobile

Tags: android

I am new in android enviroment and my question may be silly.

I developed a small app and I want to transfer it in my mobile.

I follow the steps from manifest file 'Use the Export Wizard to export and sign an APK'.

I transfer it in my mobile but I can't install it. I use the 'easy installer' application to install the apks.

Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

I have some 3rd party apps on my mobile and I can install them. So the settings from my mobile  I assume that are correct.

Thanks

Comment: check updated 3rd point and link in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

> You need to enable USB debugging on the phone itself (by starting the
>   Settings application and selecting Applications > Development > USB
>   Debugging), install the Android USB device driver if you haven’t
>   already (Windows only), and then plug the phone into your computer
>   using the USB cable that came with the phone. Close the emulator
>   window if it’s already open. As long as the phone is plugged in,
>   Eclipse will load and run applications on the phone instead. You need
>   to right-click the project and select Run As > Android Application.

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned that you have developed small application, so you can directly run your application into your mobile through USB cable attached with it, before that check the below points in your real device(i.e. mobile or tablet):

1. settings->applications->Unknown Sources, check it true
2. settings->applications->Development->USB Debugging, check it true
3. After checking this, just type **`adb devices`** command at command prompt(cmd prompt path should be upto **platform-tools** directory , which you can find inside your android folder), once you run this **`adb devices`** command, it will list **List of devices attached**

if your device is listed successfully (otherwise it displays ???????) then you are able to run application in that particular devices directly.

If you are still facing trouble then go through this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

Comment: hello @PareshMayani  is it possble to test two android app in same device ,if possible how to ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you allow “Unknown Sources” in the Application Settings?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "can't install it" ? Error message or anything ?

Check if you allowed unknown applications from the menu/settings/applications as advised by Patrick

Then here's my workflow :

- Connect the phone via usb
- Activate usb disk
- Copy the apk somewhere
- Deactivate the usb disk
- Launch a file manager (I personally use Astro)
- Browse to the file click it
- Choose open with "application manager"
- Click install

Comment: why need to download Astro kind of application if he/she can directly run their developed application via USB cable into mobile?

Comment: Because A) The op said he can't B) He doesn't asks how to debug the app on its mobile from eclipse, but how to transfer a signed apk and install it on its device

Comment: I tried it with astro and I don't see any install button/label. On details tab it says "could not open [path] as apk file".

Comment: @Yahel do you have any good link to guide me how to debug the app on my mobile from eclipse ( I didn't know that I can do this )

Comment: Simply go there for a step by step installation : http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html then when you open your project in eclipse use the little triangle "play" button. If your device is connected via usb it will launch the app on it. If Eclipse doesn't show your device as a target try to look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824531/eclipse-doesnt-recognize-my-android-device

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you can install:

Firstcheck -> Unknown Sources in Application Settings is Enabled or not ifnot enable.

`Using command prompt`.

Goto--> android-sdk-folder --> tools ( platform-tools ) -->

Use command `adb install yourappname.apk`

and enter.

Note: Connect only device at a time if you use this method.

Or

First move the application apk to `sdcard` then,install from market

`'appInstaller'` application.

Run app, it fetches apk  and select your apk and install it.

Hope it helps

Comment: i can easily install in a particular device if i have attached more than a device

Comment: I tried to install it with 'easy installer', a similar one to 'appInstaller' but with no luck. I think that something goes wrong with the export or the sign. I don't know.

Comment: While running easy installer are you able to see your apk, ?? if so then you select to install it after installing it doesn't seem to visible??

Comment: unfortunately it isn't visible.

Answer (score 0):

To install a signed APK, ensure to first un-install the unsigned app that you likely installed during development.Cheers!