# How to test Android app on Samsung Galaxy Tab from Eclipse?

Tags: android, galaxy-tab

I just got a Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 and want to test my app on it. I turned on USB debugging and the bumblebee in the corner confirms that it is on. When I run my app from Eclipse (Helios) on Windows 7, I don't see the Galaxy Tab in my list. All I see is my Samsung Nexus S, which is also attached via USB.

[image]

Comment: 1)Install usb drivers
2)Enable usb debugging on your device
I did all of the above but didnt work.
then i did the things in the following link http://stackoverflow.com/a/8705561/538408 and adb recognized my device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may need to install suitable drivers on your pc.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html

Comment: i have done steps for win7 but still my samsung tab is not detecting in eclipse. can you help?

Comment: I guess the drivers are not installed correctly. The easiest way to check is to run `adb devices` on the command line. If the device shows up there it will show up in eclipse too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the drivers from Samsung's website.  If you have the new 10.1 tab, it's this one:

http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads/GT-P7510MAVXAB

If not, select the right model from the drop downs.  I don't know if this is required, but I shut down Eclipse before doing this and restarted it, and my tablet showed up in the deploy to device list immediately after

Answer (score 0):

This is the link I used for the usb drivers [Samsung Downloads](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/down/cnts/toolSDK.list.do?platformId=1&cntsId=&searchText=&sortType=0&codeType=C451&nacode=&indexDirection=1&indexType=1&listLines=10&attchId=&attchName=)

Can also be found by finding it yourself [here](http://developer.samsung.com/resources.do), called "Samsung Andorid USB Driver for Windows"