# why this error occurs ""emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.helloG.CalculatorActivity activity launch'!"

Tags: android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get a emulator-5554 disconnected message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333273/why-do-i-get-a-emulator-5554-disconnected-message)

this error appears sometimes and sometimes my program run.
"emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.helloG.CalculatorActivity activity launch'!"
i do not understand why this happens,......:(
please help me.
my code is accurate by the way.

Comment: please clean your project and run it again

Comment: in Eclipse IDE menu -> projects -> clean

Comment: not yet
i tried a lot but still struck.....:(

Comment: the problem is still un solved..:(

Comment: Clean the project works for me. It solved my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to reset your adb.  go to Eclipse IDE-->window--> Show Views --> device--> view menu --> reset adb

Comment: i tried to find it but it is not there.......:(

Comment: window->show view-> Other -> Android -> Devices , and the drop down arrow will show you a list , you can find reset adb  there.

Comment: i did not find the reset adb there....:(

Comment: you have double click on devices, then a new window appears. You can find drop down arrow in that widow. let me know if you have reached at least to devices

Comment: yups i reached at the devices...

Answer (score 0):

Try this post, [adb commands](http://www.londatiga.net/how-to-use-android-adb-command-line-tool/)

navigate to android-sdk/tools/

and write 'adb reset' should work :D

Comment: adb reset is not (no longer?) a valid command