# Error:emulator-5554 disconnected:

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get a emulator-5554 disconnected message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333273/why-do-i-get-a-emulator-5554-disconnected-message)

i run mine application in eclipse and the following results found in **console**

```
[2011-09-27 12:47:58 - AndroidBlackjack] Android Launch!
[2011-09-27 12:47:58 - AndroidBlackjack] adb is running normally.
[2011-09-27 12:47:58 - AndroidBlackjack] Performing com.android.blackjack.Setup activity launch
[2011-09-27 12:47:58 - AndroidBlackjack] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'yahoo' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2011-09-27 12:47:58 - AndroidBlackjack] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'yahoo'
[2011-09-27 12:49:52 - AndroidBlackjack] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-09-27 12:49:52 - AndroidBlackjack] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-09-27 12:51:12 - AndroidBlackjack] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.android.blackjack.Setup activity launch'!
```

please help me
i do not understand this.

Comment: Have you checked if your emulator is running? It must be started before running the eclipse project.

Comment: no did not check it. how will i check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution (Eclipse IDE)

```
Select & Right Click on Android Project
Run Configurations
Go to tab Target 
Enable option Wipe User Data on Emulator launch parameters
Run Application
```

If you are using other IDE, you can restart your emulator using -wipe-data flag to delete all the temporary files that the emulator created in previous runs.

Comment: i already enable the Wipe User Data

Comment: restart the emulator.. and then try..

Comment: hmmmmmmmmmmmmm ok i will do that too

Comment: restarted the emulator even restarted the whole system but no effect

Answer (score 0):

the cancellation occurs because of three reasons:

1. i had not clean the project
   *emulator => project => clean*
2. i had written the ***.main*** in small letters in *manifest.xml* by mistake
3. i had not removed windows firewall settings of window

Answer (score 0):

The problem as I discovered lays in the fact the the project has no appropriate Virtual Device defined for it in the AVD manager.

So the recommended steps in eclipse are:

```
Go to "Project"-> Properties-> Android.
On the right pane see what line is checked in the Project build target.
Remember the target platform number that appears in the selected line.
Go to "Windows"-> AVD Manager.
Check the list of existing Android Virtual Devices for a device that matches the Platform and API level that you have set for your project (see step #2 above).
If there is no line that includes an AVD for your platform (as I suspect), add it using the "New" button.
A "Create New Android Virtual Device" window will be opened. set a new device name. in the "Target" selection box choose the right platform for your project.
```

Enjoy your emulator once again!