# How can I make eclipse connect to Android emulator manually?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, emulation

There are lots of times Eclipse can't connect to emulator that I turned on from AVD Manager, and just starts a new emulator by itself,( two emulators are the same ):((. How can I make eclipse find the emulator ?

Comment: Use Android Studio.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

some times restarting adb solves your problem

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

for working easier in command line in windows, add the path of adb.exe to that Windows' path. For example add ";C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools" to System Properties-> Advanced-> Environment Variables-> System Variables-> Path

One of the reasons of problems in device connection is a long USB cable or a two-piece cables like keyboard USB. try to connect your device to PC directly by a short cable.

Comment: That is why programmers dont like Eclipse. Nothing works as it is supposed. My Android Emulator runs fine (started from within AVD Manager), my code has no errors but still I cant debug or run it. Eclipse (Neon) always says: [MY_AVD] disconnected, blah blah blah.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that you might suffer from the issue that the manually started emulator got disconnected somehow, shown with a message like

`Error: emulator-5554 disconnected`

in the Eclipse console view. There are several related questions and answers on stackoverflow like [Why do I get a emulator-5554 disconnected message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333273/why-do-i-get-a-emulator-5554-disconnected-message),
but for me none of those answers helped.

Whenever I see the error message for disconnection occur, I just shutdown that emulator and start it again. Normally that already "fixes" the problem, it just works on the next attempt (for me).

Answer (score 1):

I was just experiencing this issue also. I agree with breceivemail, the ADB reconnected to the emulated device after reset, but there is a shortcut using Eclipse:

In the DDMS view => Devices window => View Menu (the down triangle in the header) => reset adb

Answer (score 0):

You can choose the target device manually by changing the run configurations.

Run -> Run configurations -> choose your App -> Target tab -> select "Always promt to pick device"

If your device isn't available you will at least don't start a new Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

If the emulator is still active, you can use adb to connect to it via tcp. In this way you can connect a disconnected emulator to your development system's loopback one port higher, just like if you are using emulator-5554, you can connect to it by using a higher port.

```
adb connect localhost:5555
```

There was been an issue with this technique, where the emulator control becomes inactive, and the developer cannot send GPS coordinates or SMSs or calls to emulator.

There is a one click method to do this

1. Open notepad
2. Type the below code

   @echo off

   adb connect localhost:5555
3. Save the file as your_file_name.BAT
4. Copy the file to Android SDK/platform_tools
5. Create a shortcut, give it a custom icon, use it anywhere you like

Answer (score -1):

Open the DDMS view from Eclipse, and simply click on the emulator name you want connect to in 'Emulator' tab.

Comment: if the emulator is disconnected from adb, in eclipse ddms view, emulator tab, not show the emulator.

Comment: A disconnected emulator wont be shown in DDMS view of Eclipse!

Comment: Check if there is another process of adb which was not started by Eclipse, if yes, kill that process first, then the emulator should be connected.