# Issue with 'Hello Android' tutorial

Tags: android, eclipse

I am brand new to Eclipse and Android, but somewhat familiar with Java.  That having been said, I tried to follow the 'Hello Android' tutorial from the developer site using the latest Eclipse (Galieo) and the 2.1 Android SDK,  I am on a Macintosh running Snow Leopard (OS X 10.6).  I have a default virtual device (though my target is actually for phones like my own HTC Incredible which has the snapdragon processor and of course all the latest accoutrement in smart phones).

Everything seemed to go okay until I went to `RUN>RUN` and then selected 'Android Application'.  My computer spins its wheels for a while and then I see two errors.  I have pasted the output from Eclipse below:

```
[2010-05-04 01:53:46 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2010-05-04 01:53:46 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2010-05-04 01:53:46 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2010-05-04 01:53:46 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2010-05-04 01:53:46 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'myAVD'
[2010-05-04 01:53:46 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'myAVD'
[2010-05-04 01:53:58 - HelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2010-05-04 01:53:58 - HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2010-05-04 01:53:59 - Emulator] 2010-05-04 01:53:59.501 emulator[10398:903] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
[2010-05-04 01:54:23 - HelloAndroid] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch'!
```

I never do see the text in the emulator and the emulator crashes with a message about it quitting unexpectedly.

The crash report states:

```
Process:         emulator [10472]
Path:            /Applications/android-sdk-mac_86/tools/emulator
Identifier:      emulator
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86 (Native)
Parent Process:  eclipse [10468]

Date/Time:       2010-05-04 02:25:41.153 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.6.3 (10D573)
Report Version:  6

Interval Since Last Report:          2558914 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           4
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   2
Anonymous UUID:                      C5F178C1-5290-4CA9-AD6E-E9C4F5582754

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000001fd2f000
Crashed Thread:  3
```

NOTE:  Running the emulator from the command line with:

```
iainnitro-Mac:tools iainnitro$ ./emulator -avd myAVD

2010-05-04 02:49:23.011 emulator[10556:903] Warning once: This application, or a library it
uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw 
and move to Quartz.
Segmentation fault
iainnitro-Mac:tools iainnitro$
```

yields a segmentation fault(as noted above from the terminal output).  So the emulator is dying on its own before anything can be shown.

I have tried restarting the ADB processes.

The actual code is line by line from the tutorial and I have never been able to get to the XML part yet.

I am not sure what is wrong with my environment setup or if it is just an incompatibility with Snow Leopard?  I would REALLY appreciate any help in resolving this as I am very interested in developing on this platform.

Thank-you,

Mike N Lawrence, Kansas

Comment: The QuickDraw --> Quartz warning is just that; when I built the tutorial I encountered it as well and thought it was responsible for the problems I was having with the emulator - but I just wasn't waiting long enough for the emulator to boot.  So if you're worrying about Quartz, don't.

Answer (score 3):

No direct experience, but this seems to be a recurrent issue:

[This thread](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/37f88df106f7fa2e) suggests:

> You haven't let the emulator boot all the way up. Start it then wait until you see a desktop, just like on a real phone.

[This one](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/6e5fe5a4e570273f) mentions (I suspect point 1. is not a concern for you):

> 1. Get more RAM.  I was running on 256 MB (which I believe is below minimum requirements), just upgraded today to 1024 MB (long time coming), application now starts fine.  Although I still do see some error messages in the emulator, they don't seem to actually do anything.
> 2. Install from command line.  This is a bit laborius, but you can launch an emulator from the command line (assuming `<android sdk path>\tools` is added to your PATH variable) just type emulator, then browse to the location of `your_app_here.apk`, and execute

```
adb install your_app_here.apk
```

> If you launch the emulator from Eclipse, execute `adb kill-service` and then `adb start-service` first (or `kill-server` / `start-server`.  not sure the exact commands).  Then your app will be installed on the emulator.

---

Also ([a bit old but might still be relevant](http://groups.google.com/group/android-beginners/browse_thread/thread/c9c68149021c0d01))

> Maybe the emulator is running so slow, and the adb server, or another component like "DDMS" is a little "desperate" because seems it's waiting to the emulator to iniatialize the some `HOME` aplication.
>   But the emulator is running slow, the console in Eclipse send a message: `emulator-5554
>   disconnected! Cancelling 'com.android.hello.HelloAndroid' launch!;` and the emulator continues running normally and boot it's system, but don't run application that I build.
>
> **So for that problem I run program, and when the emulator is opened, I go back to eclipse in DDMS Perspective and in the Device tab y press a button "`restart adb server`" before the console shows me the message of "`emulator-5554 disconnected!`"**.
>   I do it several times until the emulator finally boot the OS.
>   After booted the OS on the emulator, eclipse don't send that disconnect error, and "sends" the app that I've built, also the console shows messages about this.
>   Then finally appears on the mobile "Hello, Android".

Comment: the emulator actually dies on it's own with the Android_ screen up right after the last entry.  I will try the adb ideas and see if that helps, but more memory might be in order... though my machine does have 2 GB -- it is a month old Mac Mini :-)

Comment: ran emulator from the command line and it dies with a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1):

There has been a discussion on this with two proposed solutions
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=724

[Comment 17 by zachrcrowe, Jan 06, 2010](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=724#c17)
FYI - I had to change a line in the Hello Android example to read
this.setContentView(tv); in order for it to work. As mentioned above, the deprecation
warning shouldn't affect the functionality of the emulator.

[Comment 18 by mfrony, Jan 14, 2010](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=724#c18)
I had the same problem when I ran the Hello Android example. The way I solved it and
could run my first Android code was by changing the Project Build Target from 1.1 to 1.5.

Comment: I am sure that my target (and mainly installed platformm which is Android 2.1) is okay.  I am still getting 'emulator quit unexpectedly' when launching right as the last line comes up. Adding crash report info to original question.  Trying this.setTextView suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a timing issue. For some reason Eclipse attempts to load the application on to the emulator before it is "ready". I'm not sure why this occurs but I did find a work around: just start the emulator from the command line before you run the application.

1. Start clean by closing Eclipse (maybe the OP didn't exit Eclipse before he tried to run via the command line?)
2. Start the emulator via Terminal by navigating to the **android-sdk-mac_86/tools** directory and typing:

   ./emulator -avd my_avd
3. Open Eclipse and attempt to run the tutorial again using the same steps as before
4. A dialog box should open asking whether you would like to start a new AVD or use the one that is already running--choose to use the one that is already running.

Answer (score 1):

what i did was to move the circle that appears when the AVD launches to the unlock position, and there it was 'Hello, Android'!

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason, I stopped getting the segmentation fault when I added:

```
this.setContentView(tv);
```

the 'this' seemingly solved the issue.  The seg fault happens if you try to run the emulator without any .apk file I assume.  (I was getting that from the command line as well).  I hope the tutorial will be updated.

Comment: what is "tv"? It is undefined.

Comment: @AmySukumunu it is the TextView that is defined in the Hello Android Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem when I tried to run the emulator using a 4.0 AVD. It used to crash at the bootup screen and show 'Segmentation fault' in the console. I was able to fix it by increasing the SD card size of the AVD to 1GB from 32MB.

Answer (score 0):

[See Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160454/helloandroidemulator-5554-disconnected-cancelling-com-example-helloandroid-he/18628327#18628327)

[Another related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994026/failed-to-install-helloandroid-apk-on-device-emulator-5554/18628540#18628540)

This worked on Linux for me:

- Run Emulator (Wait for the home screen of the Emulator to load)
- Click Window > Open Perspective > DDMS
- In Devices Panel, click on drop down menu > Reset adb
- Run project