# Failed to install HelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554!

Tags: android

Ive seen the questions posted about this issue.  I understand it takes several minutes for the emulator to configure itself and launch.  But if Im getting the specific error:

```
[2011-05-13 08:41:36 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2011-05-13 08:41:36 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-05-13 08:41:36 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-05-13 08:41:36 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.santiapps.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2011-05-13 08:41:36 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'my_avd'
[2011-05-13 08:41:36 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
[2011-05-13 08:41:49 - Emulator] 2011-05-13 08:41:49.650 emulator[411:903] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
[2011-05-13 08:41:50 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentred
[2011-05-13 08:41:50 - Emulator] 
[2011-05-13 08:41:50 - HelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-05-13 08:41:50 - HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-05-13 08:44:33 - HelloAndroid] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2011-05-13 08:44:33 - HelloAndroid] Device API version is 12 (Android 3.1)
[2011-05-13 08:44:33 - HelloAndroid] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-05-13 08:44:33 - HelloAndroid] Uploading HelloAndroid.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-05-13 08:44:34 - HelloAndroid] Installing HelloAndroid.apk...
[2011-05-13 08:47:20 - HelloAndroid] Failed to install HelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2011-05-13 08:47:20 - HelloAndroid] (null)
[2011-05-13 08:47:22 - HelloAndroid] Launch canceled!
[2011-05-13 08:53:55 - HelloAndroid] ------------------------------
[2011-05-13 08:53:55 - HelloAndroid] Android Launch!
[2011-05-13 08:53:55 - HelloAndroid] adb is running normally.
[2011-05-13 08:53:55 - HelloAndroid] Performing com.santiapps.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch
[2011-05-13 08:53:55 - HelloAndroid] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'my_avd'
[2011-05-13 08:53:55 - HelloAndroid] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'my_avd'
[2011-05-13 08:54:06 - Emulator] 2011-05-13 08:54:06.327 emulator[460:903] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
[2011-05-13 08:54:06 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentred
[2011-05-13 08:54:06 - Emulator] 
[2011-05-13 08:54:06 - HelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-05-13 08:54:06 - HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-05-13 09:08:07 - Emulator] emulator: ERROR: unexpected qemud char. channel close
```

couldnt it be I have a bad configuration...?

Comment: thanks for he edit.  i tried adding the code tags and entering the console log, but it would only place the first line inside the code area, not the rest :(

Answer (score 47, accepted):

wait for the emulator to setup completely and then test your app. Also, I would leave you AVD open so you dont have to wait so long everytime you run your application.

When it shows the red writing, don't close anything - leave it there and then press the run button again. Worked like a charm.

Comment: It rises another instance of the emulator here. Almost crippled my machine. Does the same thing. Shows the android's home screen but not the hello world text.

Comment: in my case...whenever I get the EOF error....my emulator disappears from the DDMS.  In this case....go to a command line, do an adb kill-server and an adb start-server.  Emulator comes back.

Answer (score 8):

I was facing the same problem but i tried changing the ADB connection timeout. I think it defaults that to 5000ms and I changed mine to 10000ms to get rid of that problem. If you are in Eclipse, you can do this by going through Window -> Preferences and then it is in DDMS under Android.

Answer (score 3):

Try this: create another emulator in AVD Manager and try to run your application in the new emulator.
Hope this might help you

Comment: ok i did...This time i set the sdk to 3.0 instead of 3.1.  How do i tell it to use that new avd instead of the old one?  Or do i just erase the old one?

Comment: right click on the project and then go to run you will get the options in that select run configurations there you can tell which emulator to use

Comment: [2011-05-13 10:09:41 - Emulator] 2011-05-13 10:09:41.284 emulator[657:903] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
[2011-05-13 10:32:31 - HelloAndroid] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2011-05-13 10:32:31 - HelloAndroid] Device API version is 11 (Android 3.0)[2011-05-13 10:36:17 - HelloAndroid] Failed to install HelloAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2011-05-13 10:36:21 - HelloAndroid] Launch canceled!

Comment: at the time of creating the project what is the minimum API level which you have set?

Comment: i went to manifest and added min3, target7 and max 12.  got this: new emulator found, waiting for Home, Home is up on device, uploading helloWorld.apk to device, installing on device, then after 2 mins it failed to install on emulator and cancelled itself :(  also, im gettin a huge black android emulator screen, i guess its for tablet, how do i change it so its a phone-like sized screen instead?

Comment: ok so you want to change the configuration. go to avd manager and there while you create the emulator you specify name and then you can see wvga(800) below the name. Now click on that and you will get a drop down list from that options select HVGA and then create the emulator.

Comment: ok, when i set 3,7,12 it crashed after 2 mins.  but i saw that 3 is like 2.1 actually, so i moved it to min11,target11 and max12.  Its been going for 20 mins and nothing. same black screen.

Comment: for 2.1 you should set the min sdk version to 6 i guess at the time of creating the project. Try this

Comment: i have all the apis installed. Im not necessarily going for 2.1.  Shouldnt i try to code for the latest, 3.1 which is API LEVEL 12?

Comment: ya you can try but why don't you get used to some older versions so that you can use the latest versions more flexibly

Comment: Ok, i have the AVD set to 3.0.  And i Set the min, target and max to 7, 12 & 12 respectively.  It finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to increase the device ram size. For some Honeycomb AVDs at least, the default of 256 is insufficient, and caused me the same problem. Try at least 512.

Answer (score 0):

Go to window and preference and increase the ADB connection time out(ms) which is 500 by default. Also change the base local debugger port to more than 9000 in my case it worked.

Answer (score 0):

[See Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160454/helloandroidemulator-5554-disconnected-cancelling-com-example-helloandroid-he/18628327#18628327)

This worked on Linux for me:

- Run Emulator (Wait for the home screen of the Emulator to load)
- Click Window > Open Perspective > DDMS
- In Devices Panel, click on drop down menu > Reset adb
- Run project

Answer (score 0):

[Valen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754105/valen) answer is correct although **its nice to know when to start running the app** and **when is not ok to start the app**.Open the devices perspective. The next time you want to run an app first open the 'Android virtual device Manager' and run your avd then click on the device perspective and watch your emulator processes one by one firing up.. as soon this is done (its not fast you have to wait .. but at least you have some idea of whats going on .... a progress bar would be ideal for this place), click on your project and run as android app. On the devices perspective one more process will appear with the name of the package of your app. As soon as this happen your app is running on the device and it can be tested.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this error when the emulator has not loaded fully, "android" is flashing on your screen. In other words, it is not yet ready for the application to be installed.

Just wait till you see that the emulator is fully ready, meaning the "android" has vanished and the device screen is visible on the emulator. Now run it and the application loads smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Restart ADB server from DMOZ
or refer to this tutorial [How to solve Failed to install .apk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FDBfWTjhZd0)