# Android HelloWorld App works on 2.3.3 but doesn't on 4.1

Tags: java, android, mobile

I created an Android project using eclipse. It consists of one activity which simply prints hello world.

I created two AVDs to test it, one with api version 2.3.3 and the other with 4.1. If I run it on the 2.3.3 one, the app works. On the 4.1 however, it doesn't. Here's the log of the console from when I try to run it on the 4.1 :

```
[2012-10-03 01:54:07 - firstApp] Android Launch!
[2012-10-03 01:54:07 - firstApp] adb is running normally.
[2012-10-03 01:54:07 - firstApp] Performing com.example.firstapp.MainActivity activity launch
[2012-10-03 01:54:13 - firstApp] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'NewAPI'
[2012-10-03 01:54:51 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
[2012-10-03 01:54:51 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
[2012-10-03 01:54:53 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
[2012-10-03 01:54:53 - Emulator] 
[2012-10-03 01:54:53 - firstApp] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-10-03 01:54:53 - firstApp] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-10-03 01:58:16 - firstApp] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-10-03 01:58:16 - firstApp] Uploading firstApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-10-03 01:58:17 - firstApp] Installing firstApp.apk...
[2012-10-03 02:00:26 - firstApp] Failed to install firstApp.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2012-10-03 02:00:26 - firstApp] (null)
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: That sounds for me like an emulator issues. Have you tried use exactly the same settings for 4.1 emulator as you used for 2.1?

Comment: @MarcinS Yeah the settings are the same, the only setting different was the heap size. I changed it to 24 on the 4.1 avd, and now the app is getting installed and started, but after that, I'm getting an error in the LogCat tab saying `error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)`

Comment: Not sure why this error occurs. I got this sometimes too and it disappears occasionally.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6005712/603744 might be helpful