# Xamarin - App Not Appearing On Emulator

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator

I've just downloaded `Xamarin` sample and installed `HAXM`. Emulator actually works and I can do stuff with the phone, but my app won't appear. And when I close the emulator, VS says `Deploy FAILED`with a message box and on the Debug Log:

```
1>------ Derleme başladı: Proje: Dokuza, Yapılandırma: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  Dokuza -> C:\Users\seher\OneDrive\Belgeler\visual studio 2017\Projects\Dokuza\Dokuza\bin\Debug\Dokuza.dll
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\layout\main.xml
1>    Processing: obj\Debug\res\values\strings.xml
2>VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone dağıtmayı başlat ...
2>VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone öykünücüsü başlatılıyor...
2>C:\PROGRA~2\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\emulator.EXE -partition-size 512 -no-boot-anim -avd VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone -prop monodroid.avdname=VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone
2>Hax is enabled
2>Hax ram_size 0x40000000
2>HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
2>emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
2>emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
2>VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone öykünücüsü çalışıyor.
2>Öykünücünün hazır olması bekleniyor...
2>...
2>VisualStudio_android-23_x86_phone dağıtılıyor...
2>Oluşturma başlatıldı.
2>"Dokuza.csproj" projesi (Install hedef):
2>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\\bin\keytool.exe -list -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android -keystore "C:\Users\seher\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" 
2>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\\bin\jarsigner.exe -keystore "C:\Users\seher\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg md5withRSA -signedjar bin\Debug\\Dokuza.Dokuza-Signed-Unaligned.apk "C:\Users\seher\OneDrive\Belgeler\visual studio 2017\Projects\Dokuza\Dokuza\obj\Debug\android\bin\Dokuza.Dokuza.apk" androiddebugkey 
2>No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2047-09-14) or after any future revocation date.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\zipalign.exe 4 "C:\Users\seher\OneDrive\Belgeler\visual studio 2017\Projects\Dokuza\Dokuza\bin\Debug\Dokuza.Dokuza-Signed-Unaligned.apk" "bin\Debug\\Dokuza.Dokuza-Signed.apk" 
2>device 'emulator-5554' not found
2>"Dokuza.csproj" projesini oluşturma tamamlandı.
2>Oluşturma başarılı oldu.
========== Oluşturma: 1 başarılı, 0 başarısız, 0 güncel, 0 atlandı ==========
========== Dağıtım: 0 başarılı, 1 başarısız, 0 atlandı ==========
```

EDIT: Mainactivity.cs doesn't get called at all.

Comment: Does the problem also occur when you use a different emulator image? An English debug log would help a bit more. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36333875/6192895) snippet, it should change the logging language in the IDE as well.

Comment: @TimKlingeleers This time, even If I closed emulator, visual studio debug log was stuck, and won't let me debug.

Comment: Go to Build -> Configuration Manager and check the respective Deploy checkbox for your Xamarin.Android project

Comment: @Yupi It is already checked

Comment: @TimKlingeleers I've noticed that MainActivity.cs never gets called.

Comment: It seems Visual Studio cant find your emulator, you could refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5994026/failed-to-install-helloandroid-apk-on-device-emulator-5554

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT After doing some updates, it worked. (API 25 Update)