# Android Code Works On 2.3 But Not On 4.0

Tags: android, version, gesture, gesture-recognition, onfling

I have written the following code designed for API version  2.3.3 minimum and works fine on an emulator designed for that. I have just tried testing the same code on API 4.0 and the onFling gestures I've implemented to control the app don't work. They don't even seem to be called.

Here is the code.

```
package com.mystraldesign.memorable;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.ClipboardManager;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.mystraldesign.memorable.PassGen;

public class MemorableActivity extends Activity implements android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,OnDoubleTapListener  
{
    //Define text views
    private TextView textView1;
    private TextView textView2;
    private TextView textView3;
    private TextView textView4;

    //Previous password holder
    private String prevPass;

    //Gesture Detectors
    private GestureDetector gTap; 

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        gTap  = new GestureDetector(this,(android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener) this);

        //Remove title bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);




        //Define textView
        textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        //Load font file
        Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/optima.ttf"); 

        //Set various textViews to font
        textView1.setTypeface(type);
        textView2.setTypeface(type);
        textView3.setTypeface(type);
        textView4.setTypeface(type);

        prevPass = "Memorable";

    }



    //Password call
    public void newPass()
    {
        //Store Return
        String retn = "";
        PassGen passWord = new PassGen();


        //Generate password
        try 
        {
            retn = passWord.passwordGen(this);
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {

            //Message about Error
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Ooops Something Went Wrong!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            //Display message
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();

            textView1.setText("Memorable");


            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        //Update prevPass
        prevPass = textView1.getText().toString();

        textView1.setText(retn);
    }









    /*--------------------------------------*/
    /*Additional gesture code below. */
    /* */
    /*J. Krawczyk 3/5/12*/
    /*--------------------------------------*/



    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent me){ 
        this.gTap.onTouchEvent(me);
       return super.onTouchEvent(me); 
      }



    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {

      return false;
    }

    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
          float velocityY) 
  {

    String test = textView4.getText().toString();
    if ((velocityX == 0) && (velocityY > 0))
    {

        //Call new password generation or generate random if set
        if(test.equals("Memorable"))
        {
            newPass();
        }
        else if(test.equals("Random"))
        {
            //create new password method
            PassGen pass = new PassGen();

            //Set password
            textView1.setText(pass.randomPassword());
        }
    }
    else if((velocityX == 0) && (velocityY < 0))
    {
        textView1.setText(prevPass);
    }
    else if((velocityY == 0) && (velocityX > 0))
    {

        if(test.equals("Memorable"))
        {
            textView4.setText("Random");
        }
        else if(test.equals("Random"))
        {
            textView4.setText("Memorable");
        }   
    }


    return false;
  }


    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) 
    {

    }


    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
      float distanceY) {

     return false;
    }


    public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {

    }

    public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {

     return false;
    }


    //Method to copy password - Depreciated
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

     return false;
    }

    //Method to copy password
    public boolean onDoubleTapEvent(MotionEvent e) {

        //clipboard shite
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
        clipboard.setText(textView1.getText());

        //Message about coping
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Password has been copied to clipboard.";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        //Display message
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();

      return false;
    }



    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {

     return false;
    }





}
```

The console keeps saying it fails to install but it appears on emulator and runs. The same happens when testing on an actual 4.0 device.

```
2012-05-03 05:57:06 - Emulator] 2012-05-03 05:57:06.471 emulator-arm[5445:1107] Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
[2012-05-03 05:57:06 - Emulator] emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
[2012-05-03 05:57:06 - Emulator] 
[2012-05-03 05:57:06 - Memorable] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2012-05-03 05:57:06 - Memorable] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2012-05-03 05:59:24 - Memorable] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-05-03 05:59:24 - Memorable] Uploading Memorable.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-05-03 05:59:26 - Memorable] Installing Memorable.apk...
[2012-05-03 06:01:34 - Memorable] Failed to install Memorable.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2012-05-03 06:01:34 - Memorable] (null)
[2012-05-03 06:01:34 - Memorable] Failed to install Memorable.apk on device 'emulator-5554': EOF
[2012-05-03 06:01:34 - Memorable] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: EOF
[2012-05-03 06:01:34 - Memorable] Launch canceled!
```

EDITED:

It now runs and installs on all AVD's (2.3.3 - 4.0) but the gestures still only work on 2.3.3

Comment: Are you getting errors, if yes then please post your logcat too.

Comment: @RobinHood No errors but posted console output which says failed to install despite it being there and running.

Comment: I don't know but seem like your issue. [emulator window was out of view and was recentered](http://www.coderanch.com/t/546671/Android/Mobile/emulator-window-was-out-view)

Comment: That link isn't about Failure To Install On AVD

Comment: +1 i hope somebody look this..who have worked on 4.0 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to error of gesture not being recognised was due to me using velocity to determine movement but it is finer controlled on Android 4.0 so was never hitting the velocityX = 0 condition.

Answer (score 1):

I have few suggestions for you,

1) You first open your avd and wait until its get loaded completely and then run your apk.

2) change your `setContentView(tv);` by `this.setContentView(tv);`

3) close/delete your other old AVD

4) If you got device with you, Test on it..

---

Links to reffer [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=724) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763395/issue-with-hello-android-tutorial)

Comment: @Frankenstien tried all of these but with no difference. Still fails to install on Android 4.0 AVD's