# Implementing geo- tagging in an Android application

Tags: android, google-maps, geotagging

So I got into Android application development quite recently and while I having been getting on alright with most of the introductory tutorials, either from the Android Developer's site or otherwise, I believe that what I want to implement may be slightly complex.

I would essentially like to do the following:

- Allow the user to post information about what they're doing in the form of a Twitter post
- Allow the user to get access to a Twitter feed in which they can see what others are doing
- Import this data into a MySQL database or appropriate
- Integrate the location data with the Google Maps API (I understand this will involve geocoding and use of php?)
- Use Google Maps API to display a map on the front end (on a different screen to where the user posts information about their activity) and show different users' locations on the map, and also information about their activity when the cursor hovers over their location

So I was wondering if anyone could suggest some good tutorials to read in order to implement the above mentioned features?

A quick question with Eclipse development on Android, why do I always get the following two errors when I try to run an application on the emulator:

- **Warning once: This application, or a library it uses, is using NSQuickDrawView, which has been deprecated. Apps should cease use of QuickDraw and move to Quartz.
  and**
- **emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example1.myApp.MyFirstActivity activity launch'!**

The second error is the more serious one as it is effectively preventing me from running my application

I have adb added to my classpath and everythingI tried restarting it but sadly the problem persists

Thanks a lot for all your replies in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use SQLite instead of MySQL. SQLite is included with the Android SDK. This tutorial helped me: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Neil

Comment: This might be relevant to your Eclipse problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763395/issue-with-hello-android-tutorial