# Error: "emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling activity launch'?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [HelloAndroid]emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch'!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160454/helloandroidemulator-5554-disconnected-cancelling-com-example-helloandroid-he)

i removed the Eclipse and than install it again and than run my program, it will run. but after some time this error came again
 emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling  activity launch'!

i did not understand why it happens again and again....:(
i had open devices as well

Comment: Did you try closing Eclipse and all the emulators / disconnecting the devices you have connected, and then reopening eclipse? I have this issue often (Windows 7 x64)

Comment: i had restarted mine system but it came back........:( i am using windows xp

Comment: Yes do like as @hotVeryspicy said. And if possible then when ever you start adb just select the option of wipe user data. Sometimes it will be also helpfull to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Device may not have enough memory to install this .apk file. Your should Uninstall unnecessary application from settings > Manage Application > Click Uninstall onClicking Useless application and also clear data of that app.
i had also follow the steps and change the environmental settings for java 
it helped me alot and now the cancellation of emulator had almost minimal. and my program is running
do check this website
http://www.mybringback.com/bringers/java-programming/the-basics/441/setting-up-jre-on-you-computer-so-you-can-begin-java-programming/

Answer (score 35):

ya it is happening, for that just try to reset your adb  by going to "DDMS" environment open "Devices" tab and in that top right corner you have "view menu" click on it you will get an option called "**reset adb**" just do that, may helps

Comment: no effect dude
same error occurs........:(

Comment: then sorry friend no more idea on it

Comment: dude i am totally stuck with this hectic error... i had uninstall it eclipse and than error remove. now it came back.....:(

Comment: at first I got this error, then I opened DDMS and did reset ADB as per this answer, then I started getting some exceptions in eclipse DDMS logs, so I closed android emulator and relaunched app in debug mode it worked fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: +1. Worth mentioning: I typically perform the 'reset' via the command line using `adb kill-server`, then `adb start-server`. (I've found it to be a more _guaranteed_ solution)