# Android with Eclipse does not work?

Tags: java, android

i'm totally new in Android and i installed the android-sdk-windows in my laptop.
And i tried the very simple code of Hello, when i launch the code i get this error, why please?
Thank you

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (classFileParser.cpp:3375), pid=6584, tid=7084
#  Error: ShouldNotReachHere()
#
# JRE version: 6.0_24-b07
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (19.1-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\Eclipse\workspace\Now\hs_err_pid6584.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&ie=UTF-8&q=Internal+Error+(classFileParser.cpp%3A3375)) gives some great results. Some of them direct to this site as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps:

1. Run -> Run As -> Run configurations
2. Remove Android Library in the recently created JUnit configuration Classpath's Bootstrap Entries
3. Add Library, using "Advanced" button, add JRE System Library and JUnit 3
4. Apply and Run

Ref: [Diego Torres Milano's blog](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2008/11/android-testing-on-android-platform.html)

Comment: OK i understand the first step but fro the second step, i see JUnit but there is nothing under this and i don't see the Android Library, Thank you

Comment: OK after your answer i have another error message now:

Comment: what is your current error message ?

Comment: this is the error message:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/app/Activity
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

Comment: Ok i run it as android application and i have a new ugly window like a smartphone with the title: 5554:my_avd and it happens nothing

Comment: .Answer to your previous question.have you added JRE System Library ? This occurs because the classpath is not setup or referenced correctly.

Comment: Ok.Now,Your application is running without exceptions ?

Comment: I'm expecting to see Hello, Android on the new screen but i see only the Android logo  and in the console i shave this: [2011-11-26 22:07:39 - HelloAndroid] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-11-26 22:07:39 - HelloAndroid] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...

Comment: Yes here is the code : package com.example.helloandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloAndroid extends Activity {
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       TextView tv = new TextView(this);
       tv.setText("Hello, Android");
       setContentView(tv);
   }
}

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160454/helloandroidemulator-5554-disconnected-cancelling-com-example-helloandroid-he