# Emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'activity launch'! Tried to resolve with cmd commands but still not working

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am getting this error, I tried to resolve it but still it is not working.I have tried "adb kill-server" and adb start-server and also emulator -avd emulator_name -wipe-data.

I have attached the screen shoot of cmd.

I just want to run my application, but after "Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched." I got emulator-5554 disconnected error, I searched on net and from following link I tried commands

[HelloAndroid]emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.example.helloandroid.HelloAndroid activity launch'!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160454/helloandroidemulator-5554-disconnected-cancelling-com-example-helloandroid-he)

I tried to reset the adb but got following error:

```
[2012-08-06 10:12:38 - DeviceMonitor] Adb connection Error:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

[2012-08-06 10:12:39 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
```

Now, I have tried following solution that wipes user data but I do not want it.My applications need to interact with each other , with following solution it is not possible because now, I need to wipe data before running each application..:(

```
Select & Right Click on Android Project
Run Configurations
Go to tab Target 
Enable option Wipe User Data on Emulator launch parameters
Run Application
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need to restart your `ADB`

Comment: your question is not clear ,will you tell me what do you want?

Comment: Try to restart your eclipse. And,just try whatever you need..

Comment: I restarted eclipse many times.... Last time I faced this problem then it was resolved by adb kill and start server command

Comment: Can't you start emulator from Eclipse?

Comment: Are you running more than one instance of eclipse, because that can mess with the adb server?

Comment: No, I 'm not running more than one instances

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did is go to the Android Virtual Manager (AVD) and edit Memory Options: like adjusted Ram from 15 to 30 and VM Heap from 16 to 32. Since then the "emulator: 5554 diconnected! Cancelling ..." never scared me till I shut it down. It works for me, though.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `Eclipse` just go to `Windows` - `Show View` - `Device`. There is small triangle `Show menu`. Press and choose `reset adb`. Wait a little bit and run your project again.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by following these steps,

- Run Emulator
- Keep the Emulator, (no matter same error occurs)
- Make Sure the Home Screen of Emulator is appeared
- go to Window -> Show Perspective -> DDMS --> In Devices Panel -> on Corner Drop Down Menu
- Reset adb

I Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it `adb kill-server` followed by `adb start-server`