# Android AVD disconnected

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

My AVD was working before and now suddenly it doesn't load, gives me black screen and gives me this error:

```
[2014-10-21 13:36:55 - l] adb is running normally.
[2014-10-21 13:36:55 - l] Performing com.k.l.MainActivity activity launch
[2014-10-21 13:36:56 - l] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'AVD_for_3_4_WQVGA'
[2014-10-21 13:36:56 - l] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD_for_3_4_WQVGA'
[2014-10-21 13:43:03 - l] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2014-10-21 13:43:03 - l] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2014-10-21 13:43:05 - l] emulator-5554 disconnected! Cancelling 'com.k.l.MainActivity activity launch'!
```

I removed it and created a new one. Selected option 'Wipe User Data'. My Target is Android 3.2 and ADV Target also says Android 3.2. I restarted Eclipse, still the same error. It also gave me error that another instance of avd might be running, but I have nothing else running. What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Check for updates in SDK Manager, and also restart computer. Did you do any configuration change before it stopped working?

Comment: Thanks! I haven't changed anything, there are no updates and restarting computer didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Can you create AVDs with other targets and/or architectures and launch them successfully? Or none of the AVD configurations work? As a last resort, you can download a fresh install of ADT Eclipse or Android SDK and extract it to a **new** location. Then check if you can create and run AVDs in the fresh extract.

Comment: please refer these questions as this a very common problem its already asked a ton of times :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160454/helloandroidemulator-5554-disconnected-cancelling-com-example-helloandroid-he http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333273/why-do-i-get-a-emulator-5554-disconnected-message

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you face that emulator is disconnected problem, do the following.

1) Restart the adb , eigther from command prompt or if you are using windows: go to task manager and select --> Processes tab and select adb.exe and click on end process. It will restart the adb and the connection between the eclipse and Emulator will be established.

Note: There are so many way to restart the adb, but above mentioned is one way in windows.

2) You can also increase the disconnection time for the emulator.

In Eclipse--> Go to WINDOW-->Prefrences-->android-->DDMS>increase the timeout value. Increseit to 10000 or more.

Note: You dont have to recreate a new AVD or restart the AVD if you do the above things.